# How to embed a .gifv format into my webpage?

Tags: html5-video, embed, gif, webm, imgur

http://i.imgur.com/BK7Lhgp.gifv

There is a link. I dont know how to embed it. i tried `<video>` tag like:

```
<video>
   <source src="http://i.imgur.com/BK7Lhgp.gifv" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

however it did not show up. `<img>` tag also does not work. Any idea there?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply replace GIFv with webm, you should have something like this

```
<video>
   <source src="http://i.imgur.com/BK7Lhgp.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Late answer, but might help someone out there! :)